# Changing color of a BandedGridview cell Devexpress

Tags: c#, devexpress

I'm trying to change the color of a cell in a bandedgridview so, i look to the devexpress documentation http://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridView_CustomDrawCelltopic i did this all the time with a regular gridview, but the banded one doen't fire the CustomDrawCell event, i try to fire manually the event like this

```
 bandedGridView1.CustomDrawCell += bandedGridView1_CustomDrawCell;
```

but doesn't fire the event, how can i fire the event? or change de color

Note: I try every other event like RowStyle, RowCellStyle but any of those fire's, another consideration is that i'm creating the columns dinamically not from the gridview designer

Comment: Have you tried [RowCellStyle Event](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridView_RowCellStyletopic)

Comment: yes, i do, but doesn't fire

Answer (score 0):

You have to maintain global list where cell color needs to change. Once you have list then you can change color appearance of cell via [Rowcellstyle](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridView_RowCellStyletopic) event

To fire row cell style event you need to refresh datasource assigned to gridview,

```
Gridcontrol.RefreshDataSource()
Gridview.RefreshData
```